# Pentaho - Bigquery Export and Import Data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pentaho

I'm doing a Transformation steps for my BigQuery Data. I want to user Pentaho to create a job to clean up the data in BigQuery and perform scheduled inserts.

I used the **Table Input** step to query 10 (This are just limited records, since I have Billions of rows in my BigQuery table) records on my BigQuery table. Afterwards, I created **Add Sequence** step to assign row numbers into my selected rows.

After performing above steps, I used the **Table Output** step to dump the records into a different table in my BigQuery dataset. The moment I run my Pentaho Transformation, I'm getting an error on my **Table Output** step.

> 2017/12/04 07:36:02 - Table output.0 - Connected to database [bigquery 2] (commit=1000)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Because of an error, this step can't continue: 
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - Error inserting row into table [sleep_day2] with values: [3], [0], [195], [196], [0], [0], [0], [1], [2017-11-22 14:35:11], [2017-11-22 14:35:11], [2017-10-03], [1103]
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - 
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - Error inserting/updating row
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - [Simba]JDBC Null pointer exception.
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - 
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - 
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:385)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.processRow(TableOutput.java:125)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - Error inserting/updating row
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - [Simba]JDBC Null pointer exception.
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - 
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1321)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:262)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - ... 3 more
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Simba]JDBC Null pointer exception.
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQSQLExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeWithParams(Unknown Source)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeAnyUpdate(Unknown Source)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1288)
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - ... 4 more
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - ... 9 more
>   2017/12/04 07:36:04 - Table output.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=1)

I can't seem to understand the

> JDBC Null pointer exception.

its throwing. However, when I check into the destination table in BigQuery.. There is 1 row inserted. I'm wondering how come this 1 row was inserted and the other 9 rows were not.

I'm using **SimbaJDBCDriver42_1.1.2.1002** for Google BigQuery. My **PDI version is 7.1.0.0-12**

I am also aware that we can simply perform this transformation via  BigQuery WEB UI However, I am performing various transformation rules on the data. Some of which is not supported by BigQuery.

Thank You so much for the help

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing that is so complex that it's not possible to do in BigQuery itself with SQL + JavaScript? Also, just throwing this out here - why not just use Cloud Dataflow or Cloud Dataprep instead?

Comment: @GrahamPolley There is an issue in assigning unique ids for each row in google bigquery especially when using the ROW_NUMBER() function, it cant handle large volume of data. What I want to achieve in Pentaho is to create a job to handle batch cleanup and assigning of id's and dates to each rows. Do you have suggested solutions to this?

Comment: BigQuery will scale to massive dataset sizes (we regularly push 100's of TB's through it), so I'm not sure why you're saying "it cant handle large volume of data" :-/